# How to sort divs in Static html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am trying to sort divs through their internal content in static HTML page. I am able to sort the content but how can i append the complete div back to page? Any suggestions?

```js
var orderedDivs = $('.col-md-3 .card-body .card-title').sort(function(a, b) {

  return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).text().toLowerCase(), $(b).text().toLowerCase());
});
console.log(orderedDivs);
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-icon">
      <img src="#"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">John Doe</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle">Designation1</h6>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-icon">
      <img src="#"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Mary Jane</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle">Designation2</h6>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-icon">
      <img src="#"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">David Rock</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle">Designation3</h6>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: apply sorting on col-md-3 divs and inside sorting apply localCompare on title and return the element.
replace sorted divs in the parent element, I have replaced it in body.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $sortedDiv = $('.col-md-3').sort(function(a,b){
     var text1 = $(a).find('.card-body .card-title').text();
     var text2 = $(b).find('.card-body .card-title').text();
     return String.prototype.localeCompare.call(text1.toLowerCase(),text2.toLowerCase());
  });
  $('body').html($sortedDiv);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-icon">
      <img src="#"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">John Doe</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle">Designation1</h6>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-icon">
      <img src="#"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Mary Jane</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle">Designation2</h6>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-icon">
      <img src="#"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">David Rock</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle">Designation3</h6>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Can we sort this by Surname (in card Title) also?

Comment: yes we can, just replace `return String.prototype.localeCompare.call(text1.toLowerCase(),text2.toLowerCase());` by `return String.prototype.localeCompare.call(text1.toLowerCase().split(' ')[1],text2.toLowerCase().split(' ')[1]);` here we are splitting text by space and taking second part for sorting

Answer (score 0):

Add the whole html to a div and set paste back the content

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
 var orderedDivs = $('.col-md-3').sort(function(a, b) {
  return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).data('title').toLowerCase(), $(b).data('title').toLowerCase());
  });

  $("#content").html(orderedDivs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<div class="col-md-3" data-title="John Doe">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-icon">
      <img src="#"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">John Doe</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle">Designation1</h6>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="col-md-3" data-title="Mary Jane">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-icon">
      <img src="#"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Mary Jane</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle">Designation2</h6>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="col-md-3" data-title="David Rock">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-icon">
      <img src="#"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">David Rock</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle">Designation3</h6>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: but When i am inspecting the page, it is only appending <h5> tags not the complete div